# add attribute to a table so I can use css on it

Tags: angular, d3.js

I made a table containing information. But without any styling, the columns get placed right next to each other, making it difficult to see which values belong to which column. So I want to use css to make borders and some space between the columns. But i make the whole table in my angular component, there is not a single line of code of it in the html, so I have nothing I can add an attribute to which I in turn can call in the css file.
how can I add an attribute or tag to my table so I can use css on it?

```js
function tabulate(data, columns) {
      var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
      var thead = table.append('thead');
      var tbody = table.append('tbody');
      //append the header row
      thead.append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns).enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function (column) {
          return column;
        });
      //create a row for each object in the data
      var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');
      //create a cell in each row for each column
      var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function (row) {
          return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
          });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .text(function (d) {
          return d.value;
        });
      return table;
    }
```

this is what happens now, without css
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tALEY.jpg
the gene name is CD19, but as you can see, the number 19 just get pasted to the rest, which makes it a mess.

Comment: Try to use `table width:100%`

Comment: how exactly should i do that?

Comment: in your css write `table { width: 100% }`

Comment: that doesn't do anything, like i said, the css doesn't really have a class or tag that it can work on, that's why i'm trying to find out how to give my table a tag.

Comment: your table most certainly has a tag, in the very second line of your code your adding a HTML tag. Else try to open the inspector in your Browser (if you're using chrome use CTRL+SHIFT+I), find in the DOM the table tag and add css styling manually

Comment: i think you mean this? https://imgur.com/a/jTdxtaa ,  i'm unable to find a way to put css on it, maybe i should have mentioned the page has a submit button, in the component i access my database, and then make a table out of the data i get back. Maybe the css doesn't do anything because the table isn't there when the page is loaded?

Comment: See my answer with working jsfiddle, css works also when the table is added by a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to separate the columns and make each one more visible in the sense that they are more seperated, you need to add more css. Take an example here

https://jsfiddle.net/6rLe1juw/

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using your stackblitz example: what you are doing is adding the table to the body of the DOM instead of the content of your component. That's why the css won't work. Angular applies the css of the component only to elements inside the component. You could add the code above to the file `src/styles.css`. Then it will work. However, that css is applied on the root of the application.... 
Alternatively, I would propose to use e.g. [Material tables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)

Here is a forked example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqchzp-wr8fco?file=src/styles.css

Comment: i placed the css exactly like that in the css file, but it still doesn't do anything, my table doesn't turn red nor gets widened. my component calls the css file (which is in the same directory) with ```styleUrls: ['./cluster-tool.component.css']``` and my first css line ```@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');``` does work. so i just don't understand why your css won't work for me, i tried using using safari in private mode, in case the problem was in the cache, but no difference.

Comment: Since I don't know more details of your entire project, it gets very difficult to say where the problem lies. Maybe you should try to create a stackblitz example https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/getting-started-v0/stackblitz.html

Comment: i sort of recreated my code in stackblitz, my code is in the product list directory: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqchzp

Comment: Check out my update. Your code adds the table outside the components, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks a lot, for now i will keep it in the src/styles.css, i have looked at the material tables link before, but it was a bit too complex for me for my current skill level in angular.